# Who are contemporary notable non materialist women in the field of philosophy of mind?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind

(It seems it is kind of difficult to post a question that fits nicely in its own title, but the fact of the matter is that it does fit)

Comment: What is materialist woman, what a non-materialist woman? :-)

Comment: Presumably a non-materialist theory of mind? Catherine Malabou, comes to mind; but I haven't read her work.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered three:

Mary Midgely -- who was contemporary at the time the question was asked, but who has since died.  She was a dualist friend and ally of Thomas Nagel.  She wrote a book only a few years ago that rebutted delusionism:  Are You an Illusion.  Pretty impressive for being 95.

Susan Blackmore -- she comes with an asterisk.  She is a delusionist, and **I** would call her a materialist, but she claims to be a neutral monist.

Kate Distin -- also comes with an asterisk, as I don't know what her ontological worldview is.  But she is the best advocate I have found for memetics, and I don't think one can really be a good memecist and not be at least a matter/ideas dualist.

Comment: to realize Susan Blackmore is actually a materialist one has to be a non-materialist, are you not?

Thanks for the pointer to Mary Midgely. I will look her papers up.

Comment: @nir, yes, I am a spiritual dualist.  I am neither prominent nor a woman though.

Comment: @nir What I CAN offer is that I have reviewed a lot of the materialist and non-materialsit philosophy of mind writings, and have in depth reviews posted on Amazon.  If you are interested in a non-materialist summary of how to address the weaknesses of materialism, and what the alternatives are, these reviews are a useful signpost:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFPX2QIO33YZWUADXIEEDZVM7THQ?preview=true

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [list](https://sites.google.com/site/philmindwomen/home) of female philosophers working in mind, with details about their specific subfields and links to their webpages. They are all contemporary and notable.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it is a general list, not a list of non materialists.